# If function not working in case of numeric characters

Tags: textbox, numbers, addition

So i have used the following code

```
If (txtbedroom + txtkitchen + txtbathroom + txtlivingroom + 0) > 9 Or (txtbedroom + txtkitchen + txtbathroom + txtlivingroom + 0) < 7 Then
    If MsgBox("Please ensure the number of rooms you entered is entered correctly.", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
    Exit Sub
    End If
End If
```

even if the result of the following is  less than 9 and greater than 7 the if function still gets satisfied... what can be done??

Comment: What language is this code in? I'm assuming it's visual basic and if it is, aren't you suppose to put parentheses around the entire if condition so it will become
`If ((txtbedroom + txtkitchen + txtbathroom + txtlivingroom + 0) > 9 Or (txtbedroom + txtkitchen + txtbathroom + txtlivingroom + 0) < 7) Then`?

Comment: Yes it is VBA. And yet doesn't work.In fact the if function does not get fulfilled no matter what the number is result is. @JohnOdom

Answer (score 0):

Anyway I solved  the problem. I used a variable and the code CInt() like x = CInt(txtbedroom) to convert the text to number and then it worked...

Comment: Wow, I don't know why I didn't see that lol. I'm glad you find the answer :).